# Controlling scope of \displaystyle

Tags: math-mode

I know I can use \displaystyle in front of a single command, or in the preamble to the document. Is there anything in between? In particular, can I put everything in a given *environment* in displaystyle, without marking up each command individually or extending the scope to the whole document?

For instance,

```
\begin{myenvironment}[display]
    & y = f(x) \\
    & x = \frac{1}{2}
\end{myenvironment}
```

to achieve the same effect as

```
\begin{tabular}
    & \displaystyle y = f(x) \\
    & \displaystyle x = \frac{1}{2}
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: The question is a bit vague. Could you add a specific example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @campa I've given an illustration.

Comment: Sorry but this is still not very clear: apart from the mismatched brace, the content of `align` is in `\displaystyle` anyway.

Comment: @campa Yes, the content of align is in \displaystyle, by marking up each line individually. Here there are two lines, so it didn't take that long. If there were many lines, it would take longer, so it would save a significant number of keystrokes to have the math marked up automatically, rather than manually and line-by-line. I could do that using \everymath{displaystyle} in the document preamble, but that would be overkill, since I don't necessarily want displaystyle everywhere. So I would like to define environments which make their contents \displaystyle automatically.

Comment: No, my point is that the cells of `align` are *always* in `\displaystyle` even if you do not write anything. That's how `align` is defined.

Comment: @campa OK, that was unintentional. I've changed the example to tabular.

Comment: @mjc that's also a bad example as that is incomplete and would never compile as `tabular` cells are text, not math. Do you mean `array`? It is probably better if you example what exactly it is you are trying to some there.

Comment: @daleif The exact example is a tabular environment with columns customised to be in math mode by default, similar to David Carlisle's new answer below.

Comment: @mjc but posting your question with inexact examples that are incomplete and generate errors unrelated to the question doesn't really help anyone to help you.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I was aiming for a minimal example. I now see that the information I left out was needed. Thanks for helping figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement that you can use `\displaystyle` in front of a command is misleading, it would not (just) apply to that command it would apply to the rest of the current group.  Similarly you can not use it in the preamble (other than in a definition that is later used in math mode).

Your `tabular` example would give errors as tabular cells are text so `\frac` is an error.

With `array` package loaded you could use

```
\begin{array}{>{\displaystyle}c>{\displaystyle}c}
 a & b
\end{array}
```

To have two columns in display style but you should almost never do this. `array` is for setting matrices and arrays and the cells are best set in text style.  Equations as in your examples are best set in a display math environment that uses `\displaystyle` by default such as `align` from `amsmath`.

```
\begin{align}
   y &= f(x) \\
   x &= \frac{1}{2}
\end{align}
```

Comment: As it happens I arrived at something like your first example moments before you posted. What I specifically want to do is write two-dimensional equations, with equals signs going up-down as well as left-right, with the up-down ones aligned centrally to the expressions they're equating. The tabular environment, with columns customised to display math by default, is the solution I've arrived at, and now I know how to put them in displaystyle by default. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: @mjc wouldn't something like `tikz-cd` be better for that?

Comment: @mjc tabular isn't really suitable for commutative diagrams, tikz-cd or xypic or amscd or ... are far better for that use.

Comment: @mjc see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/commutative-diagrams

Comment: @daleif Thanks both; these look good.

Answer (score 2):

There's a flaw in the premise of the question: `\displaystyle` *cannot* be used in the preamble of the document (or outside of math mode, for that matter—`\displaystyle $\frac12$` will give an error).

That said, we can enforce `\displaystyle` on all math by writing `\everymath{\displaystyle}` which will give us the expected results of putting subsequent math in `\displaystyle`. Now if we want to restrict the scope of this, we can use TeX’s concept of *groups* to restrict it. A math environment has an implicit group which is why if I write `$\displaystyle\frac 12$ $\frac 34$` only the first fraction will be in display style. At their simplest groups are enforced by braces so, for example, I can write

```
{\everymath{\displaystyle} $\frac 12$ $\frac34$} $\frac56$
```

and the first two fractions will be in display style and the last will not.

Another place where groups come into play is with environments. The contents of an environment have a group surrounding them so if I write, for example,

```
\begin{quotation}
\everymath{\displaystyle}
$\frac12$
\end{quotation}

$\frac34$
```

Only the fraction inside the quotation will be in display style. You can, of course, incorporate the `\everymath` command into an environment definition:

```
\newenvironment{quotationwithdisplaymath}{\everymath{\displaystyle}\begin{quotation}}{\end{quotation}}
```

and then you can use the `quotationwithdisplaymath` environment as above.

Why did I put the `\everymath` before the `\begin{quotation}`? Because there are other places that groups appear silently, most notably every cell of a `tabular`, `array` or other aligned environment is its own group. So if I wrote, for example,

```
\newenvironment{myfancytab}{\begin{tabular}{cc}\everymath{\displaystyle}}{\end{tabular}}
```

then had

```
\begin{myfancytab}
  $\frac12$&$\frac34$
\end{myfancytab}
```

only the first fraction would be in display style. Moving the `\everymath` before `\begin{tabular}` would give the expected result.